# Most efficient way of traversing a node tree when there is repetition

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree

I have a slightly odd query.  A project I am working on, which because of a confidentiality clause I am limited in what I can say about it, employs the following style of node tree:

[image: Node tree with repetition]

This six-level drawing is a small sample of the 69 level full tree.  Traversing and recording the routes through the tree to get from A to K for example is common practice where there is no repetition, and doesn't cause any problems.  However, at several places in the tree we have a situation where the exit from one node connects back to an earlier node in the tree.  Think of route mapping within Sat Nav software for a more visual example.

So there are valid links from A to S as well as F to N and from A to P as well as E to I for example. There are legal and illegal routes. For example in the case of A to S, it could go A,C,F,M,S and A,C,F,M,C,F,M,S (the latter is invalid as there is repetition that isn't needed).  To be clear, Not all routes through the tree necessarily start at A.

My query is how to detect the un-necessary repetition (ie illegal routes) and what is the most economical way of traversing the tree to record the routes.  The time to traverse is not a major consideration, as the tree will be traversed and the legal routes recorded in multi-dimensional arrays.  It will only be re-run if the node links change (which could potentially be every three to four months).

Can anyone offer any thoughts on the most effective and efficient way to do this?  The software is being programmed in Java for reference.

Comment: This should not be called a tree. It is a directed cyclic graph.

Comment: You can use a standard breadth-first-search algorithm: as soon as the target node is found you have the shortest path to it, which will not have a redundant cycle.

Comment: @trincot Thanks for that.  Breadth-first-search algorithm .. ill look into that.